# API Request comments POST endpoint rejecting on Instagram

Tags: instagram

I want to post comment on Instagram using Instagram API. We need special permission for our app to post comments. I requested twice with option "Provide customer service" at https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116. But they rejected the request saying...

"We have reviewed your application and have determined that your request does not comply with our requirements for usage of this endpoint. Please note that we allow access to this endpoint solely for the following use cases:

1. A business requesting rights to media objects from the Instagram Community in order for the media to be used for display outside of Instagram.
2. A business providing customer service to members of the Instagram Community by interacting through comments.
3. A business responding to members of the Instagram Community that participate in a specific reward or coupon campaign.

Since your app doesn't appear to be serving any of these uses case, we're unable to grant access to the endpoint."

My application is under construction and is not live yet.

Do I need to publish my application before making request to get access to post comment? How do I request and what details should I include? Does anyone get access to post the comment? Please share your experience.

Comment: Did you found solution for it.

Comment: @MM-BB nope, I didn't find any solution. :(

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a request for Comments API Endpoint. The form didn't confirm this submission. Is this a normal behaviour? Didn't receive a tracking email either...

Answer (score 0):

*Facebook must approve your client_id to use this endpoint.*

https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116

Comment: It is generally helpful to include the relevant portion of a linked page in your answer/question, that way in case the link goes bad, at least the important information will be present alongside your answer/question.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!